# MySQL IF replacement for two strings

Tags: mysql, sql

Grandfathered Database, worst non normal form data I've ever witnessed.  So queries become a pain the arse.

I'm trying to match to see if the field is NOT either of these two strings..I've googled my arse off and the `REGEXP` function isn't all that great.

```
IF (SUBSTRING_INDEX(op.field_name, '-', 1) != ('CAT','DOG'),
    ps.products_productline ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(op.fieldname, '-',
    1)) AS product_type
```

The substring index are either Cat, Dog or a Unique string.

Comment: Can you guarantee the location in the string?  Wildcarding the left side of a LIKE is going to perform as well as REGEXP (not great) -- can't be helped with bad data, sorry :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Case
When SUBSTRING_INDEX(op.field_name, '-', 1) Not In('CAT','DOG') Then ps.products_productline
Else SUBSTRING_INDEX(op.fieldname, '-', 1)
End AS product_type
```

Another solution

```
Case
When op.field_name Like 'CAT-%' Then 'CAT'
When op.field_name Like 'DOG-%' Then 'DOG'
Else ps.products_productline
End AS product_type
```